# how to extract a particular paragraph from a .txt file using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file containing the information of all airports in the world. I need to use C# to read some parameters of each airport.

In the .txt file, the format is like this:

```
Airport ZSPD Latitude... Longitude...
      ...(multiple lines)
      (one blank line here)
      ...(multiple lines)
      (another blank line here)
Airport ZSSS Latitude... Longitude...
      ...
```

Now I need to extract a paragraph of one airport to read. Any ideas? Thanks!

A complete example is like this:(previously its over 600 lines and I have replaced similar lines with "...")

```
Airport KPAE :N47:54:22.8182  W122:16:53.6295  606ft
      Country Name="United States"
      State Name="Washington"
      City Name="Everett"
      Airport Name="Snohomish Co"
      in file: Scenery\0101\scenery\APX15140.bgl

      Runway 16R/34L centre: N47:54:32.3097  W122:17:08.1038  606ft
          Start 16R: N47:55:15.2970  W122:17:09.0664  606ft Hdg: 179.1T, Length 9004ft 
          Computed start 16R: Lat 47.921322 Long -122.285860
          Start 34L: N47:53:49.3225  W122:17:07.1430  606ft Hdg: 359.1T, Length 9004ft 
          Computed start 34L: Lat 47.896626 Long -122.285307
          Hdg: 179.140 true (MagVar 19.700), Asphalt, 9004 x 150 ft
          Primary ILS ID = IPAE
          Primary ILS: IPAE  109.30 Hdg: 179.1 , Flags: GS BC "ILS 16R"
          *** Runway *** KPAE0162 Lat 47.921322 Long -122.285858 Alt 606 Hdg 159 Len 9004 Wid 150 ILS 109.30, Flags: GS BC
          *** Runway *** KPAE0341 Lat 47.896626 Long -122.285309 Alt 606 Hdg 339 Len 9004 Wid 150
      Runway 11 /29  centre: N47:54:21.4900  W122:16:47.8649  606ft
          Start 11 : N47:54:36.4886  W122:17:10.8542  606ft Hdg: 134.2T, Length 4508ft 
          Computed start 11 : Lat 47.910278 Long -122.286575
          Start 29 : N47:54:06.4915  W122:16:24.8759  606ft Hdg: 314.2T, Length 4508ft 
          Computed start 29 : Lat 47.901657 Long -122.273346
          Hdg: 134.180 true (MagVar 19.700), Asphalt, 4508 x 75 ft
          *** Runway *** KPAE0110 Lat 47.910278 Long -122.286575 Alt 606 Hdg 114 Len 4508 Wid 75
          *** Runway *** KPAE0290 Lat 47.901657 Long -122.273346 Alt 606 Hdg 294 Len 4508 Wid 75
      Runway 16L/34R centre: N47:54:08.3055  W122:16:17.9493  606ft
          Start 16L: N47:54:22.6238  W122:16:18.1134  606ft Hdg: 179.6T, Length 2997ft 
          Computed start 16L: Lat 47.906414 Long -122.271699
          Start 34R: N47:53:53.9872  W122:16:17.7866  606ft Hdg: 359.6T, Length 2997ft 
          Computed start 34R: Lat 47.898197 Long -122.271605
          Hdg: 179.560 true (MagVar 19.700), Asphalt, 2997 x 75 ft
          *** Runway *** KPAE0161 Lat 47.906414 Long -122.271698 Alt 606 Hdg 160 Len 2997 Wid 75
          *** Runway *** KPAE0342 Lat 47.898197 Long -122.271606 Alt 606 Hdg 340 Len 2997 Wid 75
      COM: Type=10 (CENTRE), Freq=128.50, Name="SEATTLE"
      COM: Type=13 (ASOS), Freq=128.65, Name=""
      ...
      Taxipoint #0, type 5 (?):  N47:54:07.1069  W122:16:23.6608  -- Forward
      Taxipoint #1, type 5 (?):  N47:54:07.1069  W122:16:28.0026  -- Reverse
      ...
      Parking Park1 [#G0]:  N47:54:10.2492  W122:16:42.0037
          Type 2 (GA Ramp Small), Size 10.0m, Hdg 225.1T
      Parking Park2 [#G1]:  N47:54:09.2126  W122:16:40.5185
          Type 3 (GA Ramp Medium), Size 14.0m, Hdg 225.1T
      ...
      Gate P11 [#G7]:  N47:55:09.3365  W122:16:49.9781
          Type 10 (Heavy Gate), Size 36.0m, Hdg 90.0T
      Gate P10 [#G8]:  N47:55:03.7646  W122:16:50.0650
          Type 9 (Medium Gate), Size 23.0m, Hdg 90.0T
      ...
      Parking Park8 [#G14]:  N47:53:50.9422  W122:16:43.1112
          Type 3 (GA Ramp Medium), Size 14.0m, Hdg 179.1T
      Parking Park9 [#G15]:  N47:53:50.8774  W122:16:47.3646
          Type 3 (GA Ramp Medium), Size 14.0m, Hdg 179.1T
      ...
      Gate G12 [#G19]:  N47:54:00.1422  W122:16:45.1389
          Type 8 (Small Gate), Size 18.0m, Hdg 90.7T
      Gate G13 [#G20]:  N47:54:00.1422  W122:16:55.6108
          Type 9 (Medium Gate), Size 23.0m, Hdg 270.0T
      ...
      Parking Park13 [#G34]:  N47:54:15.4971  W122:16:47.2985
          Type 12 (?), Size 16.0m, Hdg 314.7T
      Parking Park14 [#G35]:  N47:54:13.6830  W122:16:42.5816
          Type 3 (GA Ramp Medium), Size 14.0m, Hdg 43.6T
      ...
      Taxipath (Name #0):  Type 3 (Parking), Start#=24, End#=G0, Wid=21.34m
      Taxipath (Name #0):  Type 3 (Parking), Start#=25, End#=G1, Wid=21.34m
      ...
      Taxiname:  #0 = 
      Taxiname:  #1 = A1
      ...
    TaxiWay : G0-24-25-G1
    TaxiWay : G2-26-81-80-79-1-78
    ...
      FSM A/P KPAE, lat=47.906342, long=-122.281563, alt=606
```

What I need to read is the Airport ID, the altitude, latitude, longitude and Hdg of each Runway, Gate and Parking Park (some Airports do not have Gates and Parking Parks), the length and ILS of each Runway.

I need to read them into a DataTable - therefore, the information of each Runway, Gate and Parking Park occupies 1 line in the DataTable.

Which way should I use to extract the data I want and to distinguish an Airport from another Airport in this .txt file? I need some ideas. Thank you very much!

Comment: What you want to read from this? provide example.

Comment: That's unclear and too broad. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have updated my question with a complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I way is to use regex like this:

```
var txt = @"Airport ZSPD Latitude... Longitude...
  ...(multiple lines)
  ...(multiple lines)

  ...(multiple lines)
  ...(multiple lines)
  ...(multiple lines)

Airport ZSPD Latitude... Longitude...
  ...(multiple lines)
  ...(multiple lines)

  ...(multiple lines)
  ...(multiple lines)
  ...(multiple lines)";

var result =
    Regex.Matches(
        txt,
        @"^airport\s+(?<ap>\S+)\s+(?<lat>\S+)\s+(?<lng>\S+)\s+(?<p1>[\s\S]+?)^\s*$(?<p2>[\s\S]+?)(^\s*$|(?!\s)$)",
        RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(
            c =>
            new
                {
                    Airport = c.Groups["ap"].Value,
                    Latitude = c.Groups["lat"].Value,
                    Longitude = c.Groups["lng"],
                    Paragraph1 = c.Groups["p1"],
                    Paragraph2 = c.Groups["p2"]
                })
        .ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

[**C# demo**](http://rextester.com/CIDB72357)

Answer (score 0):

Best approach for this is to convert text file into better formatted file type eg .xml

```
String[] data = File.ReadAllLines("yourTextFileName.txt");
XElement root = new XElement("root",
                            from item in data
                            select new XElement("Line",item));
root.Save("SaveFileName.Xml");
```

Then read XML tags

```
var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText("SaveFileName.xml");
var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);

var result = str.Elements("word").Where(x => x.Element("Airportname").Value.Equals("Hethro")).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```